# Is it valid to let a neural network predict the actual value y without denormalizing through the normalized data x?

Tags: regression, neural-networks, loss-functions

Let's assume I have a regression task. My data is numerical with x as the input data and y as the target variable.

What I usually do is that I normalize my data with both x and y. Then I feed it into the network (f.e. a MLP) and get a prediction. The prediction then is used to calculate the loss through mean squared error. Normally I'd simply let my loss be calculated by the MSE of the normalized prediction and normalized y. My loss is always between 0 and 1. For the final prediction I inversed the normalization algorithm and got the "real" prediction.

Now I had to use two frameworks together and tried out SK-Learns Standard Scaler, which only normalizes the values of x. So I tried out to feed my normalized data x into the network and calculate the loss through the prediction and the DENORMALIZED y. The curves seem good to me and the network starts to perform fairly well even on the validation set.

When I think about it in theory it simply would "reverse" the normalization by itself by learning the real values. Also the results seem to be good so I don't assume it's an actual mistake.

However is the second approach even valid? Or does it simply worsen the performance of the network?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean if you have to predict on a normalized scale?

Comment: @Dave Basically yes. Does the y-label also have to be on the normalized scale or is it valid to only have the data x on the normalized scale

Comment: Valid in order to accomplish what? It can sometimes be helpful to normalize (numerical optimization can be easier), but, in most situations, it is hardly a requirement.

Comment: @Dave To accomplish a numerical prediction through regression. Normalization is also done in both cases, but in scenario A I normalize only x and in scenario B I normalize x and y. I understand that it's not a requierment to normalize, but does scenario B pose any disadvantages in comparison to scenario A?

Comment: There could be some numerical funkiness, but normalizing is basically changing the units. It doesn’t matter if you predict in feet or meters. If you have one, you can get the other. When you predict on the normalized data and then transform those predictions to the original scale, how do they compare to the predictions made directly on the original scale?

Comment: @Dave Yes that's how I understood normalization. But in my case I basically changed the units just for x and let my neural network change them back itself without telling it how I did it in the first place.

Comment: If you know, as you acknowledged, that normalizing the outputs is unnecessary, why do you assume that not doing something unnecessary has disadvantages?